# Why the core dns doesnt resolve any domain name when firewalld is enabled? It works when firewalld is stopped

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have enabled all required ports. When i enable the firewalld service then the core-dns doesnt resolve any domain-name with command `$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a know case, which you can find on GitHub [Fresh deploy with CoreDNS not resolving any dns lookup #1056](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1056).

There seems to be few solutions which would mean different problems.

One being:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

**Please remember this is not recommended.**

Another solution might be:

Adding `iptables -p FORWARD ACCEPT`.

Also check if `core dns daemon controller` has enough resources, as this might be causing restarts.

You need to provide more details regarding your cluster so we can pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may originate due to forwarding packets between interfaces. There are two options:

First, for sessions, I also recommend this for testing:

```
$ vim /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# set to 1
```

For a more permanent solution:

```
$ vim /etc/sysctl.conf
# ADD net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
$ sudo /sbin/sysctl  -p
```